# Can't get PFX/SSL to work in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-server-2012-r2, pfx, server.xml

I'm having problems setting up SSL on Tomcat7. I have a PFX file exported with a private key and however I try, i keep getting the following error when starting Tomcat, saying:

> keystore password is incorrent

I've verified with both in IIS & OpenSSL that the password is indeed correct.

I'm running Windows Server 2012 R2 and have Tomcat running as a Windows Service, running as LOCAL SYSTEM (default installation)

**Server.xml**

```
      <Connector port="8443"  scheme="https" secure="true"
                 protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                 maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
            <SSLHostConfig>
                <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/mypfx.pfx"
                             keystoreType="PKCS12" keystorePass="mypass" />
            </SSLHostConfig>
        </Connector>
```

**catalina.log**

```
07-Dec-2016 01:56:25.253 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:970)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:245)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:875)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:213)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:558)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:968)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:187)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:185)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:101)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
```

Answer (score 0):

your config should say **"certificateKeystorePassword"** instead of "keystorePass"

"keystoreType" is also not a valid parameter for , it should just be "type"

pls refer to tomcat documentation for correct parameter names:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html

Comment: "keystoreType" should actually be "certificateKeystoreType", not "type". "certificateKeystoreType" is the type of the keystore file, "type" is the type of the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the beneath code:

```java
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreType="PKCS12" keystoreFile="conf/mypfx.pfx" keystorePass="mypass" 
                           ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
        />
```